# Leute vs. Menschen vs. Völker?

Tags: word-usage, usage

An earlier question ([see here](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7648/menschen-vs-leute)) asked for the difference between *Menschen* and *Leute*. I would like to understand how "Volk" relates to these (like in the Reichstag inscription, see picture below). Is it more professional or something? I mean, it's carved on the Reichstag building, so it's pretty significant... Several dictionaries listed it as more 'folks', but I'm not sure that connotation matches things like this- [image] It seems like a very formal usage, at odds with a 'rustic folk' connotation.

How does this compare to the others? They all seem to mean "people," but with different connotations. What are the differences?

Comment: To my mind, make it explicitly asking for something not covered by dictionaries. My close vote was for being general reference. And the answer as is does not add anything valuable to dictionaries. Kinda an indicator that your question isn't that specific. On the other hand, you've got already 3 open votes, I guess it'll be open in a couple of hours anyway. — Also take note of a meta post I created with respect to the issue at hand: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1273/1224

Answer (score 7):

There is no word *Volken*, it's **das Volk**. It means ***»the people«***, as in the first sentence of the U.S. constitution:

*We the People …*

> Wir, das Volk …

*Volk* means the whole of the people of a country, in contrast to the individual people.

It's often used in a political context but also in compounds as **Fußvolk**, **Bienenvolk**, **Volksfest**, **Volksbank**, and **Volkswagen**.

Comment: One might add that it corresponds to the singular *people*, with plural *peoples*, not the uncountable *people*.

Comment: Perhaps helpful for understanding: das Volk (Nom.), des Volkes (Gen.), **dem Volke** (Dat.), das Volk (Akk.). Die Völker (Nom.), der Völker (Gen.), den Völkern (Dat.), die Völker (Akk.).

Comment: Statt auf die Rechtschreibung einzugehen, die nicht die Frage, wenn auch fragwürdig war, solltest Du die Frage bzgl. der Rechtschreibung korrigieren und dann beantworten, was gefragt ist. Sonst zieht sich die Rechtschreibfehlerdiskussion durch den Thread und hält die Leute sogar vom Korrigieren ab, weil das die Themenverfehlung der Antworten dann umso deutlcher hervorhebt.

Comment: Ich sehe nicht, wo ich mehr als unbedingt nötig auf der Rechtschreibung rumgeritten hätte.

Answer (score 6):

*Volk* refers to people in the "ethnic" or national sense of the word. The *reference* to rustic "folk" is actually a formal one (even if you don't believe that rustic folk themselves are formal).

*Leute* is a collective noun referring to "people" generally, not to specific kinds, or groups of people, like *Volk*.

*Menschen* is the plural of individuals, and is better translated as "persons," than as "people."

Comment: So if I was, say, a Canadian national in Germany, at first I would only fall under Leute until I fit into culture a bit more, then become Volk?

Comment: @Imperator: If you are with Canadians, singing the Canadian national anthem, you would be a member of the Canadian "Volk." But if you are with a group of "random" people of different nationalities at a sports event, then I'd use "Leute." The exception might be, if everyone else were German, and you had "naturalized" German, then you would also be part of the German "Volk" rather than random "Leute."

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for the great answer!

Comment: @Imperator: You can accept my answer if you like it.

Comment: Let's not be hasty here ;)

Comment: @Imperator: I agree. I like to wait a few days to give others a chance to respond. Although the question is already one day old.My preference is to only upvote on the first day.

Comment: I'll give it a bit longer. You never know what might pop up.

Answer (score 4):

*Volk* shares its root with English folk. Not surprisingly, it has the same meaning as the English word (as defined at [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/folk)) in several aspects.
In a plain and general sense, it divides people into groups of culture, history, descent or language.

The word, however, covers much more meaning than this. The population or citizens are a *Volk* (*das deutsche Volk*). And so is a herd of animals, a swarm of insects etc. (*Bienenvolk*).
And the working or lower classes (the common people) are called *Volk* (*gewöhnliches Volk*). In the latter case, you can interchange the word with the other words.

Except for the sense of "lower or working classes", there's a plural: "Völker".

For reference:
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Volk
https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Volk
http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Volk

The difference between *Menschen* and *Leute* is already well covered in the question you linked. And there's also a question covering the difference between *Personen* und *Menschen*: ["Personen" or "Menschen"](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/4386/1224).

Hence, here's just a very short summary:

*Leute* is basically a collective noun and means people in general. It shares some meaning with *Volk* and *Menschen* when it comes to the sense of "common people".
But it can be used for any group of random people. Like "guy" in "you guys" or "folk" in "Hey folks". It's also used for family or friends ("Meine Leute"). Both senses are unique to *Leute* and neither *Volk* nor *Mensch(en)* can be used here.

Finally, *Menschen* is the plural of *Mensch* which represents a human individuum. Both *Volk* and *Leute* cannot refer to a single person.

Comment: "Single individuum" is a bit of a tautology. Perhaps better write  *... which - in one of its meanings - represents a human individual*. (There is also the meaning of *Mensch* as for the species.)

Answer (score 1):

1. Leute = a group of Menschen
2. Menschen = the beings belonging to the species Homo Sapiens Sapiensis
3. Volk = a group of Leute that have a certain ethnic background. Related to tribe/Stamm.

Also see Abstammung. [https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutschstämmige](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutschst%C3%A4mmige)

Normally a Volk belongs to one Nation-State/Area of settlement. 
See point two: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Volk

Comment: So a Volk is a group of group of Menschen?